# No property emplyoee found for type Emplyoee while creating custome method query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

i have a emplyoeRepo that extends the JpaRepository and i have created two method given below ,these contains service layer and service implementation layer, but when ever i run the program that gives following types of error and i don't know how to solve these issue please help me .

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emplyoeRepo': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.infodev.training.rohit.crudeoperation.Entity.Emplyoee com.infodev.training.rohit.crudeoperation.repository.EmplyoeRepo.findByEmplyoee_email(java.lang.String)! No property emplyoee found for type Emplyoee!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1828) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1265) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.infodev.training.TrainingApplication.main(TrainingApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.infodev.training.rohit.crudeoperation.Entity.Emplyoee com.infodev.training.rohit.crudeoperation.repository.EmplyoeRepo.findByEmplyoee_email(java.lang.String)! No property emplyoee found for type Emplyoee!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:218) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:84) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:84) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:244) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:169) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property emplyoee found for type Emplyoee!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:82) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

my entity class is:-

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "emplyoee")
public class Emplyoee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private int Emplyoee_Id;

    @Column(name = "emplyoee_name")
    private String  emplyoee_name;

    @Column(name = "emplyoee_address")
    private String emplyoee_address;

    @Column(name = "emplyoee_email")
    private String  emplyoee_email;


}
```

my service layer:-

```
public interface EmplyoeeService {
    Emplyoee saveEmplyoee(Emplyoee emplyoee);

    List<Emplyoee> saveEmplyoees(List<Emplyoee> emplyoee);

    List<Emplyoee> getEmplyoee();

    Emplyoee getEmplyoeeById(int emplyoee_Id);


    String deleteEmplyoeeById(int emplyoee_Id);

    Emplyoee editEmplyoee(Emplyoee emplyoee);

    Emplyoee editEmplyoee1(int id, Emplyoee emplyoee);

    Emplyoee getEmplyoeeByName(String emplyoee_name);

    Emplyoee getEmplyoeeByEmail(String emplyoee_email);
}
```

my serviceImpl class is:-

```
@Service
public class EmplyoeServiceImpl implements EmplyoeeService {
    @Autowired
    private EmplyoeRepo emplyoeRepo;

    @Override
    public Emplyoee saveEmplyoee(Emplyoee emplyoee) {

        return emplyoeRepo.save(emplyoee);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Emplyoee> saveEmplyoees(List<Emplyoee> emplyoee) {

        return emplyoeRepo.saveAll(emplyoee);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Emplyoee> getEmplyoee() {
        return emplyoeRepo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Emplyoee getEmplyoeeById(int emplyoee_Id) {
        return emplyoeRepo.findById(emplyoee_Id).orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Emplyoee getEmplyoeeByName(String name) {

        return emplyoeRepo.findByEmplyoee_name(name);

    }

    @Override
    public Emplyoee getEmplyoeeByEmail(String email) {

        return emplyoeRepo.findByEmplyoee_email(email);


    }


    @Override
    public String deleteEmplyoeeById(int emplyoee_Id) {
        emplyoeRepo.deleteById(emplyoee_Id);
        return "emplyoee is removed " + emplyoee_Id;
    }

    @Override
    public Emplyoee editEmplyoee(Emplyoee emplyoee) {
        Emplyoee existingEmplyoee = emplyoeRepo.findById(emplyoee.getEmplyoee_Id()).orElse(null);
        existingEmplyoee.setEmplyoee_name(emplyoee.getEmplyoee_name());
        existingEmplyoee.setEmplyoee_email(emplyoee.getEmplyoee_email());
        existingEmplyoee.setEmplyoee_address(emplyoee.getEmplyoee_address());
        return emplyoeRepo.save(existingEmplyoee);
    }

    @Override
    public Emplyoee editEmplyoee1(int id, Emplyoee emplyoee) {
        Emplyoee existingEmpyoee = emplyoeRepo.findById(id).orElse(null);
        existingEmpyoee.setEmplyoee_name(emplyoee.getEmplyoee_name());
        existingEmpyoee.setEmplyoee_address(emplyoee.getEmplyoee_address());
        existingEmpyoee.setEmplyoee_email(emplyoee.getEmplyoee_email());
        return emplyoeRepo.save(existingEmpyoee);

    }
}
```

and my Repositoryclass is:-

```
@Repository
public interface EmplyoeRepo extends JpaRepository<Emplyoee, Integer> {
    Emplyoee findByEmplyoee_name(String emplyoee_name);

    Emplyoee findByEmplyoee_email(String emplyoee_email);


}
```

Comment: Not sure if I am correct, did not work often with JPA, but I think the problem is that your table name is "employee" while the Class name is "Employee". And the Exception complains about no property employee for type Employee. I had the same problem using AndroidRoom.

Comment: Just a note: would be good to fix typos in your names: `Emplyoee` → `Employee`.

Answer (score 4):

Underscore is a reserved charecter for Spring Data Jpa. Spring uses underscore to understand the relation between multiple entities while preparing queries.

The solution is to remove underscore from your entity fields. Just change `emplyoee_name` to `emplyoeeName` and `emplyoee_email` to `emplyoeeEmail`;

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "emplyoee")
public class Emplyoee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private int Emplyoee_Id;

    @Column(name = "emplyoee_name")
    private String  emplyoeeName;

    @Column(name = "emplyoee_address")
    private String emplyoeeAddress;

    @Column(name = "emplyoee_email")
    private String  emplyoeeEmail;


}
```

And change your repository

```
@Repository
public interface EmplyoeRepo extends JpaRepository<Emplyoee, Integer> {
    Emplyoee findByEmplyoeeName(String emplyoee_name);

    Emplyoee findByEmplyoeeEmail(String emplyoee_email);


}
```